# Calculate total wage for a shift?

Tags: php, mysql

Let say

A staff works from 2016-12-31 23:30 PM to 2017-01-01 06:30 AM.

Here, I need to calculate total wage rate from following rule:

```
Rule#  | Date       | StartTime | EndTime | WageRate(HR)    
1      | 2016-12-31 | 07:00     | 23:59   | 25
2      | 2017-01-01 | 00:00     | 06:00   | 40
3      | 2017-01-01 | 06:00     | 11:30   | 30
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to calculate the weighted average of the hourly rate?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate total wage rate for the shift from shift rule 1,2 ,3

Answer (score 1):

The following below will work with PHP. I've used a dummy array as an example.

```
$arr = [

        ['Date'=>'2016-12-31', 'StartTime' => '07:00', 'EndTime' => '23:59', 'Rate' => 25],
        ['Date'=>'2017-01-01', 'StartTime' => '00:00', 'EndTime' => '06:00', 'Rate' => 40],
        ['Date'=>'2017-01-01', 'StartTime' => '06:00', 'EndTime' => '11:30', 'Rate' => 30]

];

function salaryCalc($start, $end, $rate) {

    $timeStart = strtotime($start);
    $timeEnd = strtotime($end);
    $diff = $timeEnd - $timeStart;
    $diffHours = round(($diff/60)/60); //I'm guessing you will pay them for the hour
    return $diffHours * $rate;

}


foreach($arr as $v) {

   echo 'Wage: ' . salaryCalc($v['StartTime'], $v['EndTime'], $v['Rate']); 
   echo '<br>';

}
```

**Output:**

```
Wage: 425
Wage: 240
Wage: 180
```

*Edit:*

I'm all for helping people, but since your last clarification of your question, it seems clear to me that you have no intention of even trying to resolve this issue by yourself, so until you provide some code which shows to me and others effort, I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select Rule,Date,StartTime,Endtime,WageRate,
-1 * timediff(StartTime,EndTime) * Wagerate as total
from hr;
```

if you calculate based on hours

Answer (score -1):

The result should be as below:

```
On 2016-12-31
23:30- 23:59. =29 min  rate can be taken from rule #1


On 2017-01-01
00:00 - 06:00 = 6hr rate apply from rule #2
06:00 - 06:30. =30min rate apply from rule #3
```

Comment: I tried by increasing start worked hour by one hour but it fails in case of rule#1 and rule#2

Any help will be greatefull for me.